# Getting URI from Bitmap [java.lang.NullPointerException]

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

I'm trying to get a `URI` from `bitmap`, using the code below, I'm able to do this, but I notice my app crash on some users devices with the following report :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init> (Uri.java:495)
  at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init> (Uri.java:485)
  at android.net.Uri.parse (Uri.java:457)
  at maa.app.Activities.BaseActivity.getImageUri (BaseActivity.java:667)
  at maa.app.Activities.BaseActivity.lambda$onCreate$28 (BaseActivity.java:606)
  at maa.app.Activities.-$$Lambda$BaseActivity$otrrnQa86F40OaLtsUupF4NjzEs.onClick (-.java:2)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6648)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:6620)
  at android.view.View.access$3100 (View.java:787)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:26167)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:891)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7539)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

here's the medthod to get `URI` from `bitmap`

```
public static Uri getImageUriFromBitmap(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
            return Uri.parse(path);
        }
```

UPDATE :

```
  private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        File file = new File(path);
        return Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
```

Comment: you're saying for some devices it's working fine, then that's may be the compatibility issue. Have you called runtime permission?

Answer (score 1):

Uri.parse(String) requires you to have a URI, not a path.  To get a Uri from a path use Uri.fromFile()

Comment: You mean like this `Uri.fromFile(new File(path));`

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work, please see my update post

Answer (score 0):

Let first call the permission if you're using APILevel >=21 otherwise it'll return **null** path and maybe crash your app.

**Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Code**

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```